# How to create a chart of cumulative sums per date from a chart of sums per date?

Tags: charts, google-sheets

I have that kind of data in a google spreadsheet:

```
      | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3
Marc  |  10   |  5    |  8
Amy   |   -   |  15   |  3
```

What I would like is a chart that shows that marc had a total of 10 on day 1, 15 on day 2 and 23 on day 3 and Amy didn't exist on day 1 then had 15 on day 2 then 18 on day 3.

The ideal would be an automated solution that generates directly the chart but I guess i could extract some data to an other sheet and use for my chart. For instance:

```
      | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3
Marc  |  10   |  15   |  23
Amy   |   -   |  15   |  18
```

If that's the only solution, how would I generate such a table automatically based on the input of my first table knowing that new names may be added and each day a column will be added ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Simple way**

Just make plot with bars and see cumulative sums in chart. You won't see exact number though:

[image: 1]

---

**Hard Way**

Or prepare another table with new calculated sums. Suppose, your data is placed on sheet \1/. Add another sheet and paste formulas:

- `="1!R2C2:"&"R"&COUNTA('1'!A:A)+1&"C"&counta('1'!1:1)+1` in cell `A1` to count work range
- `={'1'!B1:1}` in cell `B1` to copy 'Days' labels.
- `={'1'!A2:A}` in cell `A2` to copy names

And finally paste this hard formula in cell `B2`:

```
=mmult(ArrayFormula(MMULT(ArrayFormula(row(INDIRECT(A1,0))^0),SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE("-"&INDIRECT(A1,0))),"-"))*ArrayFormula(--(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE("-"&if(COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1,0)),row(INDIRECT(A1,0))))),"-")=ArrayFormula(row(OFFSET('1'!A2,,,COUNTA('1'!A:A))))))),ArrayFormula(--(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE("-"&if(row(INDIRECT(A1,0)),COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1,0))))),"-"))<=ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET('1'!B1,,,1,COUNTA('1'!1:1)))))))
```

Then plot your new calculated data to make something like this:

[image: 2]

Note that I changed "-" by 0 to make data look like numbers.

Also zero's are listed as empty string ''. This is made by custom number format: `0;0;`

Please, look at [Working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1piTVn2HncbRaruILcm6a13TNirfHPTxmkoX4neeXa8k/edit?usp=sharing)